# iOS 7, PhoneGap 3.1 with pushplugin not receiving registrationid

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

I have everything working in phonegap 2.9, and I changed to 3.1 now I can not receive registrationid from iOS when register. and no error message either, just, nothing happens.